# Using regex in Twig replacement patterns in Views

Tags: views

I am trying to output a field as a custom link using the rewrite configuration with Twig replacement patterns in Drupal 8 Views, as depicted in the screenshot below.

```
Views field: (W)here is New York?

Desired output: example.com/posts/where-is-new-york
```

In the Views field configuration, I have selected:

```
Rewrite results: Output this field as a custom link
```

and entered a few different regex patterns, to no avail. The result I get is always:

```
example.com/posts/%28w%29here%20is%20new%20york
```

Is there a third-party plugin for PCRE-style regex filters for Drupal 8? Or is this something that must be handled in a template file, i.e. views-view-field.html.twig?

[image: As depicted here.]

Comment: Try to alter the output of a field view by implementing the    HOOK_preprocess_views_view_field().